# In Dart, can you use an operator in a Case statement from a Switch Case?

Tags: dart

In Dart, can you use an operator like OR (`|`) in a `case` from a Switch Case statement?

Like, e.g.:

```
  switch (status) {
    case "succeeded" | "failed":
      buttonText = Text("Start again!");
      break;
    case "started":
      buttonText = Text("Stop");
      break;
    default:
      buttonText = Text("Start");
      break;
  }
```

Of course I tried this and it seems not, but I was wondering if there's a short an elegant way to do it, saving a `case` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case` values must be compile-time constants, so no. (The `|` operator (bitwise OR) would not do what you want anyway.)

In your case, you instead want to have multiple case-labels:

```dart
  switch (status) {
    case "succeeded":
    case "failed":
      buttonText = Text("Start again!");
      break;
    ...
```